# Developer Certificate is not creating For BB 10 in Eclipse For Android Runtime

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, keytool, blackberry-10

I am trying to sign an Android Application and run into my BlackBerry 10 Device. I installed the BlackBerry Plug-in for Android Development Tools and BlackBerry Tools SDK in Eclipse 3.7. Now I am trying to register with the RDK and PBDT keys after clicking the Register Button in the Bar Signer Window( In Eclipse, Preferences ->BlackBerry-> BlackBerry Tools SDK--> Bar Signer). After giving the path for the keys and password, it is registering the key and one mail i got saying the key is successfully registered.

Now when i trying to create the Developer Certificate, after giving the keystore password and author name, it is giving the error

[image: Error Snapshot]

In the targets of the Eclipse(Preferences ->BlackBerry-> BlackBerry Tools SDK--> Targets), My BB 10 device is showing. It means my device is recognized by the eclipse.

Now I am really confused, how to generate the debug token and or developer certificate although my device's Development Mode is ON. 
It will be great help if anyone tell me the solution..

Comment: The plugin was recently updated from beta to final. Have you tried installing the latest Eclipse plugin from: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/downloads/eclipseplugin/

Answer (score 1):

If Eclipse is not playing nice, you can always register with the RIM signing authority and create a developer certificate from the command line. You will need to add the BlackBerry tools SDK to your path first. Since you already have the Eclipse plugin installed they can be found here ([standalone tools are available here](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools)):

```
 $ECLIPSE_INSTALL_DIR/plugins/net.rim.ajde_1.3.0.201209131728/blackberry.tools.SDK/bin
```

Now you can run:

```
blackberry-signer -register -csjpin PIN -storepass <chooseapassword> RDKCSJFile PBDTCSJFile
```

where the PIN is the one you specified when requesting your code signing key.

[More info on command line tools here](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/topic/configure_app_signing_from_cmd_line.html)